# convert row to column using Pivot without any clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a table like below.

[image]

I need to get the data like below.

[image]

I have created two temp tables and achieved the result like this. Please help me to do the same with PIVOT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least I wouldn't use pivot for that, to my mind this is simpler to do with group by and row_number:

```
select UserId, max(starttime) as starttime, max(endtime) as endtime
from (
  select UserId,
    case when StartOrEnd = 'S' then time end as starttime,
    case when StartOrEnd = 'E' then time end as endtime,
    row_number() over (partition by UserID order by time asc) 
      + case when StartOrEnd = 'S' then 1 else 0 end as GRP
  from table1
) X
group by UserId, GRP
order by starttime
```

The derived table splits the time into start / end time columns (to handle cases where only one exists) and uses a trick with row number to group the S / E items together. The outer select just groups the rows into the same row.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31e70/1)

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 or newer you could also use LAG / LEAD

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot :)

Comment: Very nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a efficient solution as JamesZ but should work

```
create table #tst (userid int,start_end char(1),times datetime)
insert #tst values
(1,'S','07-27-2015 16:45'),
(1,'E','07-27-2015 16:46'),
(2,'S','07-27-2015 16:47'),
(2,'E','07-27-2015 16:48'),
(1,'S','07-27-2015 16:49'),
(1,'E','07-27-2015 16:50')

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY times) rn,*
         FROM   #tst),
     cte1
     AS (SELECT a.userid,
                a.start_end,
                a.times,
                CASE WHEN a.userid = b.userid THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS com,
                a.rn
         FROM   cte a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN cte b
                             ON a.rn = b.rn + 1),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT userid,
                start_end,
                times,
                (SELECT Sum(com)
                 FROM   cte1 b
                 WHERE  b.rn <= a.rn) AS row_num
         FROM   cte1 a)
SELECT USERID,
       starttime=Min(CASE WHEN start_end = 's' THEN times END),
       endtime=Max(CASE WHEN start_end = 'e' THEN times END)
FROM   cte2
GROUP  BY USERID,
          row_num
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method

```
declare @t table(userid int, StartOrEnd char(1),  time datetime)
insert into @t
select 1,'S','2015-07-27 16:45' union all
select 1,'E','2015-07-27 16:46' union all
select 2,'S','2015-07-27 16:47' union all
select 2,'E','2015-07-27 16:48' union all
select 1,'S','2015-07-27 16:49' union all
select 1,'E','2015-07-27 16:50'

select userid,min(time) as minimum_time, max(time) as maximum_time from
(
select *, row_number() over (partition by cast(UserID as varchar(10))
          +StartOrEnd order by time asc) as sno
from @t      
) as t
group by userid,sno
```

Result

```
userid      minimum_time            maximum_time
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2015-07-27 16:45:00.000 2015-07-27 16:46:00.000
2           2015-07-27 16:47:00.000 2015-07-27 16:48:00.000
1           2015-07-27 16:49:00.000 2015-07-27 16:50:00.000
```